# $(f_n)$ converge uniformly or not?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(f_n)$ a sequence of continuous function on $[a,b]$. Suppose that $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ for all $x\in [a,b]$ and that $f$ is continuous. Does $(f_n)$ converge uniformly to $f$ ?

I know that the answer is no, but I can't find a counter example. Could you give me one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another good, concrete example (with perhaps a simpler formula than the other suggestions): $f_n(x) = nxe^{-nx}$ on $[0,1]$ or for that matter on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: This one converge to $f(x)=0$ if $x\in]0,1]$ and $f(0)=1$, therefore the limit is not continuous...

Comment: @idm No. $f_n(0) = 0$ for all $n$. (i.e. $f_n$ converges pointwise to the zero function on $[0,\infty)$, but $f_n(1/n) = e^{-1}$, so the convergence is not uniform).

Comment: That's right. This function looks crazy since $e^{-1}=\sup f_n =f_n(\frac{1}{n})$ for all $n$, but $\lim_{n\to\infty }f_n=0$... It's definitely the best example :-)

Comment: To be fair, the other suggested examples exhibit a similar phenomenon :)

Answer (score 3):

Let $f_n(x)=\sin(nx)$ for $0\leq x\leq\frac{\pi}{n}$ and $=0$ for $\frac{\pi}{n}\leq x\leq 1$. Then $f_n(x)$ converges to $f(x)=0$  for all $0\leq x\leq 1$. But $f_n$ does not converges to $f$ uniformly.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take $[a,b] = [0,1]$

Then, you can take $f_n$ to be a piecewise linear function that connects the points

$$(0,0), (\frac1n, 1), (\frac2n, 0), (1,0)$$

I believe you should have no problem in drawing this function and writing its definition precisely.

Now, $f_n(x)\to 0$ for all $x$, but there is no uniform convergence. Again, both of these things are easy to see.